# ROP chain gadget - does jmp cause an issue

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, exploit

As part of a personal project I'm working on a ROP chain, and was looking for a gadget like so; `pop ecx; pop eax;`, being an imperfect world I found the below two, and was wondering if `jmp ecx` would mess up my ROP? Alternatively I can use `pop ecx; add al, 0xf6; ret;`, however, I suspect it would be harder to deal with `add` vs `jmp`.

```
pop eax; ret;
pop ecx; jmp ecx;
```

For a bit more context I want; `pop ecx; ret;` to put the first part of my string in `ecx` and `pop eax; ret;` to get the memory address to write too into eax register.

Would apriciate any insight you could provide?

**Update:**

Changed ecx register to esi as i had better gadgets.

Comment: Based on the two gadgets you need, and the gadgets  you've found, I would say they are incompatible. `pop eax; ret;` isn't enough since you need `pop ecx` to execute first. `pop ecx; jmp ecx;` will almost certainly cause issues unless `ecx` is magically the address of the `pop eax; ret;` gadget.

Comment: Thank you, I thought as much. I'll have to rethink the aproach. Would you know if in my shell code I could deal with the add instruction above such that it does not affect my ROP?